# Undefined Reference with inline Destructor

Tags: c++

I have a class that I inline'd the constructor and the destructor and I also have a static method for that class. I called that static method inside of the inline destructor, but I'm having a linker error undefined reference for that static method. I'm pretty sure it is compiled and link with the object. Here is the code,

```
// CFoo.h
namespace barname {
class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo();
    ~CFoo();

    static void fooMethod();
};

inline CFoo::CFoo()
{
}

inline CFoo::~CFoo()
{
    fooMethod();
}
}

// SomeOtherSource.cpp
namespace barname
{
    void CFoo::fooMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

It seems the code is fine and compiling.

Comment: `inline CFoo()::CFoo()` and `inline CFoo()::~CFoo()` isn't even valid C++. If you're taking the time to strip down to a SSCCE, thank you, and please try to post real code that actually *compiles*, because contrary to your question's comment, this does *not*. (and fixed, this compiles fine on clang).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you're describing (after fixing the syntax errors). Seems like your SSCCE above failed to capture something important in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified working version of the code

[Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60fe15d11a802c3c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace barname 
{
    class CFoo
    {
    public:
        CFoo();
        ~CFoo();

        static void fooMethod();
    };

    inline CFoo::CFoo()
    {
    }

    inline CFoo::~CFoo()
    {
        fooMethod();
    }

    void CFoo::fooMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "in fooMethod" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    barname::CFoo *f = new barname::CFoo();
    delete f;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. But fooMethod was defined in another source files.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef con001_CFoo_h
#define con001_CFoo_h

namespace barname {
class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo();
    ~CFoo();


    static void fooMethod();
};
inline CFoo::CFoo()
{

}

inline CFoo::~CFoo()
{

}

}

#endif
```

in other file

```
#include "CFoo.h"
namespace barname
{
void CFoo::fooMethod()
{
}
}
```

compiled ok in XCode 4.6